# Deploying WPF Application with database

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

I have made a Wpf application and i am using linq to SQL classes also i have made my database in SQL server 2012 so is there any way that i can deploy my application in such a way that it will run on other PC's?

Answer (score 1):

Check your app.config file. Make sure your connection string contains:

1. valid DataBase address
2. Valid credential for the db

As your update:

> whenever i make setup file and run on another pc it give me exception
>   because sql server isnt installed on that pc

Either you need to deploy a database in internet, accessable by your app. Or you have to use an embedded sql db (e.g. add a db.mdf to your solution). I think this suit you better.

Comment: @deeip they are valid

Comment: then you have no other reason to worry about regarding db connection

Comment: @deeip whenever i make setup file and run on another pc it give me exception because sql server isnt installed on that pc

Comment: @deeip well the data doesnot update in embedded sql db thats why i choose sql server in the first place

Comment: If you need a global data for all app instance you have to use Sql server. If you only need local data and mdf is not working, you are doing it wrong.

Comment: i only need local access but when ever i insert data using query in the embedded sql it doesnt update it always show previous data

Comment: post that version in another question. There must be something missing there